# How to use minElement in swift array

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to get the indexpath with the smallest row number. I am trying to use this code but I don't understand how to implement minElement.

```
try  self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems().minElement(<isOrderedBefore: (NSIndexPath, NSIndexPath) throws -> Bool)
```

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630061/get-the-smallest-indexpath-from-an-array.

Answer (score 0):

You can give `minElement` a block of code to help it compare two things that can't be compared with the standard `<`.

The syntax is a bit different in Swift 2 and 3.

Here's an example where it finds the `MyIndex` struct with the lowest `row` value:

```
struct MyIndex {
    let row: Int
}

let array = [MyIndex(row: 3), MyIndex(row: 1), MyIndex(row: 2)]

// Swift 2
let firstIndex = array.minElement { a, b in
    return a.row < b.row
}

// Swift 3
let firstIndex = array.min { a, b in
    return a.row < b.row
}
```

So in your case, it's very similar:

```
self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems().minElement { a, b in
    return a.row < b.row
}
```